# Yosemite: can I get rid of the default finder view for the home directory?

Tags: macos, finder, osx-yosemite

In Yosemite, the home directory seems to be tied to an hybrid view which I personnaly don't like. 
Is there a way to get back to the normal finder view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four view selections found under the View menu of the Finder Toolbar. These also have short cuts.

⌘1 - as Icons

⌘2 - as List

⌘3 - as Columns

⌘4 - as Cover Flow

Besides being able to readily switch between views a folder will retain it's last view, that information is stored in a hidden file named `.DS_Store` in each folder.

There are other viewing options you can explore under the View menu affecting how the finder window itself is displayed.

Comment: woa. So simple, once you know it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 4 key commands to quickly change view, you can more finely-hone what you wish to see by selecting any Finder window & then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  or View menu > Show View Options…

[image]

There are also a couple of good introductory guides in the Finder Help Menu -
"Get to know your Mac" &
"What's new in OS X Yosemite"